# Python Config Parser (Duplicate Key Support)

Tags: python, configuration, yaml, config

So I recently started writing a config parser for a Python project I'm working on. I initially avoided configparser and configobj, because I wanted to support a config file like so:

```
key=value
key2=anothervalue

food=burger
food=hotdog
food=cake icecream
```

In short, this config file is going to be edited via the command line over SSH often. So I don't want to tab or finicky about spacing (like YAML), but I also want avoid keys with multiple values (easily 10 or more) being line wrapped in vi. This is why I would like to support duplicate keys.

An my ideal world, when I ask the Python config object for food, it would give me a list back with ['burger', 'hotdog', 'cake', 'icecream']. If there wasn't a food value defined, it would look in a defaults config file and give me that/those values.

**I have already implemented the above**

However, my troubles started when I realized I wanted to support preserving inline comments and such. The way I handle reading and writing to the config files, is decoding the file into a dict in memory, read the values from the dict, or write values to the dict, and then dump that dict back out into a file. This isn't really nice for preserving line order and commenting and such and it's bugging the crap out of me.

A) ConfigObj looks like it has everything I need except support duplicate keys. Instead it wants me to make a list is going to be a pain to edit manually in vi over ssh due to line wrapping. Can I make configobj more ssh/vi friendly?

B) Is my homebrew solution wrong? Is there a better way of reading/writing/storing my config values? Is there any easy way to handle changing a key value in a config file by just modifying that line and rewriting the entire config file from memory?

Answer (score 0):

Crazy idea: make your dictionary values as a list of 3-tuples with line number, col number and value itself and add special key for comment.

```
CommentSymbol = ';'
def readConfig(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    if not f:
        return
    def addValue(dict, key, lineIdx, colIdx, value):
        if key in dict:
            dict[key].append((lineIdx, colIdx, value))
        else:
            dict[key] = [(lineIdx, colIdx, value)]
    res = {}
    i = 0
    for line in f.readlines():
        idx = line.find(CommentSymbol)
        if idx != -1:
            comment = line[idx + 1:]
            addValue(res, CommentSymbol, i, idx, comment)
            line = line[:idx]
        pair = [x.strip() for x in line.split('=')][:2]
        if len(pair) == 2:
            addValue(res, pair[0], i, 0, pair[1])
        i += 1
    return res

def writeConfig(dict, filename):
    f = open(filename, 'w')
    if not f:
        return
    index = sorted(dict.iteritems(), cmp = lambda x, y: cmp(x[1][:2], y[1][:2]))
    i = 0
    for k, V in index:
        for v in V:
            if v[0] > i:
                f.write('\n' * (v[0] - i - 1))
            if k == CommentSymbol:
                f.write('{0}{1}'.format(CommentSymbol, str(v[2])))
            else:
                f.write('{0} = {1}'.format(str(k), str(v[2])))
            i = v[0]
    f.close()
```

Comment: and you need another function to add value to dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Well I would certainly try to leverage what is in the standard library if I could.

The signature for the config parser classes look like this:

`class ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser([defaults[, dict_type[, allow_no_value]]])`

Notice the `dict_type` argument. When provided, this will be used to construct the dictionary objects for the list of sections, for the options within a section, and for the default values. It defaults to `collections.OrderedDict`. Perhaps you could pass something in there to get your desired multiple-key behavior, and then reap all the advantages of `ConfigParser`. You might have to write your own class to do this, or you could possibly find one written for you on PyPi or in the ActiveState recipes. Try looking for a bag or multiset class.

I'd either go that route or just suck it up and make a list:

```
foo = value1, value2, value3
```

Comment: I tried and failed, mainly because the _read method of the RawConfigParser uses the same dictionary to parse multiline values, write them in a list as mapped object of the key. And do another pass at the end to join everything in the dictionary. So you'll end up with something like `{'key': ['value'], 'key': 'value'}` and need a really bad hack to make it work.