# Getting all the values under a section in config file using Python

Tags: python, parsing, configparser, configuration-files

I want to get all the fields under a Section in a config file into a list. Problem with ConfigParser is, it does not allow duplication of Options.Is it possible to use ConfigParser to do so or do I need to read the whole file and put the fields of a Section line by line? Below is not exact data but similar:

```
[Data]
Version   = 2.0
Length    = 14 
ID        = 1123
Signature = ABCD
ID        = XYZ
```

Also tried with configparser's strict=False, but it is not working.

Comment: Please show us an example config file that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling duplicate keys with ConfigParser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921323/handling-duplicate-keys-with-configparser)

Comment: Please check out those questions: [configparser-duplicate-keys-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095471/configparser-duplicate-keys-in-python) and [handling-duplicate-keys-with-configparser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921323/handling-duplicate-keys-with-configparser)

Comment: @JagodaSokół, Those solutions did not solve my problem.