# How to ConfigParse a file keeping multiple values for identical keys?

Tags: python, python-2.7, configparser

I need to be able to use the `ConfigParser` to read multiple values for the same key. Example config file:

```
[test]
foo = value1
foo = value2
xxx = yyy
```

With the 'standard' use of `ConfigParser` there will be one key `foo` with the value `value2`. But I need the parser to read in both values.

Following an [entry on duplicate key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396144/python-config-parser-duplicate-key-support/5396653#5396653) I have created the following example code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from ConfigParser import RawConfigParser

class OrderedMultisetDict(OrderedDict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):

        try:
            item = self.__getitem__(key)
        except KeyError:
            super(OrderedMultisetDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
            return

        print "item: ", item, value
        if isinstance(value, list):
            item.extend(value)
        else:
            item.append(value)
        super(OrderedMultisetDict, self).__setitem__(key, item)


config = RawConfigParser(dict_type = OrderedDict)
config.read(["test.cfg"])
print config.get("test",  "foo")
print config.get("test",  "xxx")

config2 = RawConfigParser(dict_type = OrderedMultisetDict)
config2.read(["test.cfg"])
print config2.get("test",  "foo")
print config.get("test",  "xxx")
```

The first part (with `config`) reads in the config file us 'usual', leaving only `value2` as the value for `foo` (overwriting/deleting the other value) and I get the following, expected output:

```
value2
yyy
```

The second part (`config2`) uses my approach to append multiple values to a list, but the output instead is

```
['value1', 'value2', 'value1\nvalue2']
['yyy', 'yyy']
```

How do I get rid of the repetitive values? I am expecting an output as follows:

```
['value1', 'value2']
yyy
```

or

```
['value1', 'value2']
['yyy']
```

(I don't mind if EVERY value is in a list...). Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After a small modification, I was able to achieve what you want:

```
class MultiOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(value, list) and key in self:
            self[key].extend(value)
        else:
            super(MultiOrderedDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
            # super().__setitem__(key, value) in Python 3

config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser(dict_type=MultiOrderedDict)
config.read(['a.txt'])
print config.get("test",  "foo")
print config.get("test",  "xxx")
```

Outputs:

```
['value1', 'value2']
['yyy']
```

Comment: I have no idea why `super(OrderedDict, self)` works but not `super(MultiOrderedDict, self)`.

Comment: Yes, perfect! Except the `super` anomaly. Maybe it *is* the baseclass of `OrderedDict` then...

Comment: Is there any way to make this return a single value instead of a list when there is only one value? ['value1', 'value2'] and yyy instead of ['yyy']

Comment: Do you have a way to make this work in python 3? I get an error: `configparser.DuplicateOptionError`, and I don't really know what I'm doing.

Comment: @bgStack15 you should set `strict` to `False`, like this: `config = configparser.RawConfigParser(dict_type=MultiOrderedDict, strict=False)`

Comment: This seems to return values with a newline character instead of an array for 2.6/2.7

Comment: I am using 3.7 and I too am getting a string separated by `'\n'`, it appears to be something related to the `configparser.SectionProxy` being returned.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer breaks `config.sections()`, it returns always an empty list (tested with Python 3.5.3). Replacing `super(OrderedDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)` by `super().__setitem__(key, value)` fixes this, but now `config.get(section, key)` returns a concatenated string, no longer a list of strings.

My solution is:

```
class ConfigParserMultiValues(collections.OrderedDict):

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self and isinstance(value, list):
            self[key].extend(value)
        else:
            super().__setitem__(key, value)

    @staticmethod
    def getlist(value):
        return value.split(os.linesep)

    config = configparser.ConfigParser(strict=False, empty_lines_in_values=False, dict_type=ConfigParserMultiValues, converters={"list": ConfigParserMultiValues.getlist})
    ...
    values = config.getlist("Section", "key") # => ["value1", "value2"]
```

The config INI file accepts duplicate keys:

```
[Section]
    key = value1
    key = value2
```

Comment: I fixed the wrong super() call in the accepted answer and sections() now works.

Comment: Stefan Bohlein solution works best for me in Python 3.5.6

Answer (score 6):

in python 3.8 you need to also add `strict=False`:

```
class MultiOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(value, list) and key in self:
            self[key].extend(value)
        else:
            super().__setitem__(key, value)

config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser(dict_type=MultiOrderedDict, strict=False)
config.read(['a.txt'])
print config.get("test",  "foo")
print config.get("test",  "xxx")
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my issues in Python 3.7.4

Answer (score 0):

More examples Multiple values in `test.cfg`.

```
[test]
foo = value1
foo = value2
 value3
xxx = yyy
```

`<whitespace>value3` append `value3` to foo list.

`ConfigParser` converts the list to a string.

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.pyc in _read(self, fp, fpname)
    552             for name, val in options.items():
    553                 if isinstance(val, list):
--> 554                     options[name] = '\n'.join(val)
    555
```

`value` before converting is always list or dict (`MultiOrderedDict`).

Try this - with it, `config.items` works:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import ConfigParser

class MultiOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self:
            if isinstance(value, list):
                self[key].extend(value)
                return
            elif isinstance(value,str):
                return # ignore conversion list to string (line 554)
        super(MultiOrderedDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)

config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser(dict_type=MultiOrderedDict)
config.read(['test.cfg'])
print config.get("test",  "foo")
print config.get("test",  "xxx")
print config.items("test")
```

Outputs:

```
['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
['yyy']
[('foo', ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']), ('xxx', ['yyy'])]
```

Another implementation `MultiOrderedDict`

```
class MultiOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self:
            if isinstance(value, list):
                self[key].extend(value)
                return
            elif isinstance(value,str):
                if len(self[key])>1:
                    return
        super(MultiOrderedDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
```

Outputs:

```
['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
yyy
[('foo', ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']), ('xxx', 'yyy')]
```

Comment: I found this comment unclear at first but now I understand that it is pointing out where in `ConfigParser` the list value gets concatenated into a string with newlines, and some workarounds that make `MultiOrderedDict` ignore the attempt to set the concatenated value.  Unfortunately those workarounds have to make certain assumptions about how `Configparser` behaves; I think I prefer something like Stefan Bohlein's answer which just re-splits the value, but this explains why that splitting is required.

Answer (score -2):

Just a little bit change to [@abarnert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21275246/1633272), otherwise it calles __setitem__ recursively, and won't stop for some reason.

ini file:

```
[section]
key1   = value1
key2[] = value21
key2[] = value22
```

Python:

```
class MultiOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    LIST_SUFFIX = '[]'
    LIST_SUFFIX_LEN = len(LIST_SUFFIX)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key.endswith(self.LIST_SUFFIX):
            values = super(OrderedDict, self).setdefault(key, [])
            if isinstance(value, list):
                values.extend(value)
            else:
                values.append(value)
        else:
            super(MultiOrderedDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        value = super(MultiOrderedDict, self).__getitem__(key)
        if key.endswith(self.LIST_SUFFIX) and not isinstance(value, list):
            value = value.split('\n')
        return value
```

Test:

```
def test_ini(self):
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    config = RawConfigParser(dict_type=MultiOrderedDict, strict=False)
    config.readfp(codecs.open('{}/../config/sample.ini'.format(dir_path), encoding="utf_8_sig"))
    self.assertEquals(config.get("section1", "key1"), 'value1')
    self.assertEquals(config.get("section1", "key2[]"), ['value21', 'value22'])
```