# MultiOrderedDict not working on Python 2.6.6

Tags: python

Using this answer and others in the thread.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15848928/25531

This works perfectly fine on my local 2.7 in my Ubuntu VM but on our Oracle Linux server that's running 2.6.6 it only returns the last entry and not all of them in a list.

Is there a way to workaround for this by any chance?

We can't upgrade the python either.

Comment: There is no `OrderedDict` class on Python 2.6; are you using a backport?

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you for that, it didn't fail, so I guess there's an Oracle one somewhere.  Let me try a different version of it.